# Continuity - Function of 2 variables

Tags: calculus, continuity

Verify if the following function is continuous:

$$ f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},\; if \;\;x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\\ 
0,if \;\; x^2 + y^2 > 1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

---

I think the only possible "problematic point" is where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. So what should I do? Calculate the limit when $x^2 + y^2 \to 1$ or we must consider more specific cases? I don't know how to write it formally.

Thanks!

Comment: Put $u=x²+y²$ and prove that $lim_{u \to{1^-}}{f(x,y)}=\lim_{u \to{1^+}}{f(x,y)}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interior and exterior of the unit disk, the functions describing those cases are continuous. The only potential problem is on the unit circle.  But at each point of the unit circle. you have a limit of zero and a function value of zero there, too.  So the function is continuous on the entire plane.

Answer (score 1):

You let d = x^2 + y^2. Then show the limit of f from either side of d->1 is the same value.